# Implementing steepest ascent to optimize probabilities

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, machine-learning, binary-search

I want to reimplement a method that involves optimization of probabilities.
The notes I got include the calculation of the gradient w.r.t. that parameter, and the notes "the derivation has a stationary point in `[0,1]`, we use steepest ascent".

I searched for hints on implementing it and found [this](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/150572) and the [Wikipedia entry on hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing). (Neither of which gives very concrete advice.)

I thought it would be a good idea to put this together with binary search and plan to implement it in the following way (pseudo-code):

```
steepest_ascent(param, min_itvl, max_itvl):
  if (max_itvl - min_itvl < 0.01):
    return param
  d = gradient(param)
  if (d == 0):
    return param
  if (d > 0):
    return steepest_ascent((param + max_itvl) / 2, param, max_itvl)
  if (d < 0):
    return steepest_ascent((min_itvl + param) / 2, min_itvl, param)
```

The whole thing is part of an iterative procedure, so it would be called like this (as it is a probability the interval is `[0,1]`):

```
 param_new = steepest_ascent(param_old, 0, 1)
```

Is there something that could obviously be improved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've implemented the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), which is different from [gradient ascent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). (I take it your function is concave?) To do gradient ascent, update `param = param + alpha * gradient(param)` repeatedly for some suitably chosen alpha > 0 (too small and the computation will take a long time, too large and it will run forever by never converging), until some convergence criterion is met.